# Heroku Postgres with Spring boot

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, heroku

I have a spring boot api that is deployed in heroku and I added the heroku addon for postgres and followed the steps they provided in [Heroku Springboot deployment guide.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku)

However when I deploy the application and run a query to register the user i get this error from the api

```
    "timestamp": "2019-12-11T05:28:28.219+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
    "path": "/register"
}
```

For registering the user all  I am doing is

```
 if(userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()).size() == 0){
                userRepository.save(user);
                return SuccessCodes.REGISTRATION_SUCCESS;
        }else{
            return ErrorCodes.REGISTRATION_ERROR_EMAIL_EXISTS;
        }
```

Any way on how I can fix this?

Comment: Is it working well on your local? I wonder that it's not related with Heroku but related with your config in entities, table, etc.

Comment: @YeWin It works fine when I connect to my local one, when I do it in heroku i get this error

Comment: When you deploy with heroku, are you sure that your DB connection is OK or not?

Comment: @YeWin it does connect fine, I tried  resetting the database, and when I redeployed it recreated all the tables